# Find duplicate enteries from collection node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to find out duplicate entries on the basis of field " name " and in the result, I want to fetch " name " and " _id ".

I have tried using aggregate function and it is returning all the result from database as null:

here is my code:

```
 ModelRestaurant.aggregate((
    // { "$group": { "_id": "$name", "count": { "$sum": 1 } } },
    // { "$match": { "_id": { "$ne": null }, "count": { "$gt": 1 } } },
    // { "$project": { "name": "$_id", "_id": 0 } }
    { $group: { "_id": "$name", "name": { $first: "$name" }, "count": { $sum: 1 } } },
    { $match: { "count": { $gt: 1 } } },
    { $project: { "name": 1, "_id": 0 } },
    { $group: { "_id": null, "duplicateNames": { $push: "$name" } } },
    { $project: { "_id": 0, "duplicateNames": 1 } }
), function (err, result) {
    if (result) {
        console.log(result)
    }
})
```

from above commented code it is giving me all id but now it is giving me null values and all the result json of 6000 with null value.

here is the field of data in collection: 
   [image]

My Schema is :

```
  var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
  var autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment');

  var ModelRestaurant = new mongoose.Schema({
      name: String,
      ownerName: String, // to be removed by checking code
      ownerID: Number,
      ownerEmail: String, // to be removed by checking code
      city: String,
      zipCode: String,
      image: [String],
      restaurantType: String,
      address: String,
      landmark: String,
      isAddedByCustomer: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false
      },
      location: {
          lat: String,
          long: String
      }
  },
  {
      timestamps: true
  });
  ModelRestaurant.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, 'Restaurants');
  ModelRestaurant.plugin(uniqueValidator);
  mongoose.model('Restaurants', ModelRestaurant);
```

Comment: Can you post your schema?

Comment: @israel.zinc added schema

Comment: By duplicates, I guess it's the name, correct?

Comment: @israel.zinc Yes by name we have to find out

Answer (score 0):

The following code should print all the duplicates:

```
db.ModelRestaurant.aggregate([
    {$group:{"_id":"$name","name":{$first:"$name"},"count":{$sum:1}}},
    {$match:{"count":{$gt:1}}}
])
```

Comment: what is $first resembles to ??

Comment: Hmm? I don't understand your question. By the way, the answer is very similar to your original query.

Comment: and does it check for lower and upper case

Comment: the query is case-sensitive. You are just trying to do by name, right? Does it solves your problem?

Comment: no, it is not returning any result even I have lots of duplicates entries.                               result is : [ ]

Comment: are you sure the names are the same? Because it worked here.

Comment: are you executing only my query? Or are you integrating it with some other code?

Comment: I am just using your query